# Arduino IDE on Linux - directory not found

Tags: arduino-ide, linux

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a chromebook through crouton. I'm trying to install the Arduino IDE. I figured out that I needed the 64-bit version of the IDE and downloaded it. Then, I started following the instructions given - I found the downloaded file, which was named `arduino-1.8.0-linux64.tar.xz`, opened it (this opened a new window in a program called Xarchiver, which listed the subfolders and files), and saw the `install.sh` file. When I right-clicked, there was no option to run it from the terminal, so I went back to the terminal and did `cd Downloads` and then tried to cd into the downloaded file. However, it said that there was no such directory. I listed the files in Downloads, and the downloaded file came up, listed in red.

How can I run the `install.sh` file? What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the archive file first.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ tar -Jxvf arduino-1.8.0-linux64.tar.xz
```